# Dimension too large for a simple tex drawing

Tags: tikz-pgf, intersections

I have relatively simple 3D drawing.  It compiles fine, but I get five "Dimension too large" errors.  How can I avoid it?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\tc}{cos(25)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ts}{sin(25)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\pc}{cos(140)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ps}{sin(140)}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x={(-\ps*1cm,\pc*\ts*1cm)},y={(-\pc*1cm,-\ps*\ts*1cm)},z={(0cm,\tc*1cm)}]
\draw[name path=i2] (1.5,0.2,0.8) -- (1.5,0.2,2.6) -- (4.5,0.2,2.6) -- (4.5,0.2,0.8) -- cycle;  
\path[name path=e2] (1.5,0,0.8) -- (1.5,0,2.6) -- (4.5,0,2.6) -- (4.5,0,0.8) -- cycle;
\draw[name intersections={of=i2 and e2}] (intersection-1) -- (1.5,0,0.8) -- (intersection-2) (1.5,0,0.8) -- (1.5,0.2,0.8);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `\path[name path=e2,bend left=0] (1.5,0,0.8) to (1.5,0,2.6) to (4.5,0,2.6) to (4.5,0,0.8) to cycle;` for the second path.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Interestingly, it works for this example, but not in the full document with other figures and text.

Comment: I do not know your full document, therefore I can not have a general answer.